# Бесконечный цикл при повторном чтении из cin

Tags: c++

```
int x = 0;

Label1:
cout << "Enter a number:\t";
cin >> x;

if(!x) // when no number is entered
    goto Label1;
```

Получается бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так писать не стоит. Совсем не стоит. Да и goto не лучший вариант. Можно делать как-то так.

```
do {
    cin.clear();
    //cin.ignore();
    cin.ignore(100500, ' ');      //skip until space   
    //promt
} while ( !(cin >> x));
```

Но помните, что ввод вида `[число]*` будет распознано как число. Особенность с++. Если надо и такое отлавливать, то читаем как строку и потом преобразовываем в число.

`cin.clear` и `cin.ignore` нужны для сброса `failbit` и предыдущего ввода соответственно, иначе всегда будет ошибка чтения.

Comment: по вашему коду если введется например "  а3 n  = 5; " в ожидании получить  5, получим 3

Comment: @ARHovsepyan знаю. через строку надёжнее конечно. Можно  в `ignore` добавить количество символов для пропуска конечно, но тут костыль уже. Если можно это сделать надёжно чисто потоками - расскажите как, будет думаю интересно)

Comment: @pavel,  а вы уже сделали